# Testing an abstract page class in wicket

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd, wicket

I'm starting out with Wicket, and am doing TDD (using `WicketTester` of course).
I came across a problem when trying to create a common layout using markup inheritance.
I looked at online examples including [this one](http://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/markupinheritance.html). However, those examples don't mention how to test the parent class.

The problem is that the parent class is abstract. This means that `WicketTester` cannot instantiate the page and it throws an exception (and rightfully so).
I thought about testing the class as a regular POJO using a mock or a fake class, but then I'll lose the ability to test the wicket components that are in that abstract parent.
Another solution I considered (until I saw the API ...) was to provide a custom `IPageProvider`, which will instantiate a fake class/mock instead of throwing an exception. However, the API doesn't seem like something that should be implemented just for one unit test.

In the meantime, I've created the parent class as a concrete class, and I test it with `WicketTester` like any other page class. However, the examples demonstrate markup inheritance specifically with an abstract class for the parent page, and it seems that, design-wise, this is the correct thing to do.

Any advice ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just create an anonymous subclass instance during testing.

```
WicketTester w = new WicketTester();
w.startPage( new AbstractPage() {} );
```

And you should of course implement all the necessary abstract methods. Also, the `AbstractPage` should have it's own html (good practice).

Comment: I didn't even know that it was possible to call `startPage` with an instance of a page rather than a class object, I must have missed that. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just make a test subclass of your abstract parent class and test that using `WicketTester`.

I've done that in similar situations and had no problem verifying the rendering and interaction of components of the abstract parent class.

Comment: How do you do that? In order to test the page, you need to provide the class object to `WicketTester`, which in turn throws an exception. Do you mean that you have an actual subclass (rather than an anonymous inner class) ? Maybe if I declare it as an inner class of the test ... that might work ...

Comment: Yes, I have done it as an inner class, or if it's needed for multiple tests, as a top-level class in the test hierarchy.